# Doctrine2 - One-to-many Association with parent name

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create a parent name field into one-to-many association in Doctrine2.

For example, we have a Meeting. This meeting can be associated with Contacts or with Accounts.

Example of data:

```
     meeting_name         | parent_name | parent_id
------------------------------------------------------
Meeting with a friend     | Contacts    | <contact_id>
Meeting with the customer | Accounts    | <account_id>
```

Is possible to implement it in Doctrine2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure. However, I'd use the parent class' FQDN  instead of its name. Aditionally you could create a [custom hydrator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes).

Alternatively you could just create two many-to-many relations, one for meeting_customer_attendees and one for meeting_friend_attendees.